# $N(α) | N(β)$, yet $α$ does not divide $β$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What would be an example of two quadratic integers in the same quadratic field for which $N(α) | N(β)$, yet $α$ does not divide $β$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb Z [\sqrt 5]$, $N(2 + \sqrt(5)) = 9 = N(3)$ but neither $3 | (2 + \sqrt 5)$ nor $(2 + \sqrt 5) | 3$.

Comment: So does N(2+(√5))|N(3)

Comment: $9 | 9$, so yes